# 1% TDS on immovable property for multiple buyers

Tags: india, property-taxes

http://blog.tdsman.com/2013/11/will-transactions-one-buyerseller-filed-form-26qb-tds-immovable-property/

Above link tells that Online statement cum Challan Form/ Form 26QB is to be filled in by each buyer for unique buyer-seller combination for respective share. E.g. in case of one buyer and two sellers, two forms have to be filled in and for two buyers and two seller, four forms have to be filled in for respective property shares.

if in case only one of the buyer (say if husband and wife are the joint buyers) has already filled the 26 QB with the whole 1% tax amount, what would be the procedure to correct it? Also what about the late fees in this case (as the whole amount is already with government, and it's just the correction)?